# Controlling Mac's front led

Tags: macos, hardware, led

For a project of mine, I'd like to control (i.e. dim, set on or off) the little LED that sits in front of macbooks (and maybe other Macs, I don't know).
Unfortunately there's no API nor help about this on the internet - the only thing I could find was about dimming the keyboard LED. Apart from that, I only know that it would for sure use the SMC chip.
I'm OK if it needs root.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you control the Apple MacBook "Sleep" light?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010713/how-do-you-control-the-apple-macbook-sleep-light)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I must agree it *is* duplicate. But things have changed since 2010, and now it is possible to control this LED !
Take a look at [xline](http://github.com/perfaram/xline). It's a project of mine, and it' s able to control the LED, through the SMC. 
Just take a look at the source code.
BTW, I'm first opening a connection to the AppleSMC IOService using IOKit, then I'm setting the LSOO key in the SMC to 01. 00 shuts the LED down. And I use LSSB key to make it *breathe*, like when the MacBook is sleeping.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! I took a look at your code and tried it - it works to set on off, but making it blink doesn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: Honestly, no. Never had this problem when testing. May I have more details ? (Such as your mac model, OSX version)